# how to download excel file on nginx + tomcat reverse proxy?

Tags: file, nginx, tomcat, reverse-proxy, xlsx

just tomcat It works, but not working with nginx....

When I request it with http: // localhost: port in a Tomcat environment it works fine. However, in the nginx reverse proxy environment there are no errors and file down does not work.

this is spring java service code mapped to url /excel/clientSampleDownload

```
//service code
public void downloadSampleExcelFileTms(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale)throws Exception {
    ...
    SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();
    response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=true; path=/");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; 
    filename=\""+newString((saveFileName).getBytes("KSC5601"),"8859_1")+".xlsx\""));
    OutputStream outputStream=response.getOutputStream();
    wb.write(outputStream);
    wb.dispose();
    outputStream.close();
    wb.close();

}
```

this is nginx config

```
//default.conf
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain;

    client_max_body_size 2000M;

    location /manageChannel {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:19912;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Origin "";
    }

    location /resources/ {
        alias   /var/www/advertise.alancorp.co.kr/static/resources/;
        autoindex off;
        access_log off;
        expires 1M;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header    X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:19912;
            proxy_redirect      off;
            charset utf-8;
            # buffer size
            proxy_buffering   on;
            proxy_buffer_size    1024k;
            proxy_buffers        1024   1024k;
            client_body_buffer_size 1024k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 1024k;

    }
}
```

What should I add to the nginx configuration

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer here: https://gist.github.com/zeroasterisk/5535517

i thought the problem is about `content-type` header.

my nginx version is `1.1.0`, add `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet        xlsx;` into `conf/mime.types`.